# Fixed navigation effect on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed-header-tables

i found this code.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
     $('nav').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
     $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
 });
```

```css
/*
Tutorial Name: Scroll To Top Then Fixed Navigation Effect With JQuery and CSS
Description: Create a sticky navigation bar that remains fixed to the top after scroll
Author: Stanislav Kostadinov
Author URI: http://stanislav.it
Version: 1.0.0 - 11.01.2014
*/

* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

a {text-decoration: none;}

/* This class is added on scroll */
.fixed {
 position: fixed; 
 top: 0; 
 height: 70px; 
 z-index: 1;
}

body {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'open-sans-bold'; 
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
}

/* Font Face Settings */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open-sans-bold';
 src: url('../fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   url('../fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
} 

/* Navigation Settings */
nav {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 background: #fff;
}

nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 24px 10px;
}

nav li a {
 color: #757575;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

section {
 height: 100vh;
}

/* Screens Settings */
#screen1 { 
 background: #43b29d;
}

#screen1 p {
 padding-top: 200px;
}

#screen2 {
 background: #efc94d;
}

#screen3 {
 background: #e1793d;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {

 nav li {
  padding: 24px 4px;
 }

 nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
 }

}
```

```html
<section id="screen1">

 <p>Scroll down</p>

 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>

</section>
 
<section id="screen2"></section>
<section id="screen3"></section>
```

Here is a working Example.  http://stanhub.com/tutorials/sticky-navigation/

Its a sticky menu and works nicely, but the problem is it only sticks then the page is scrolled all down. is it possible to fix it after the nav div is 40px scrolled down? lets say its 40 pixels between the nav box and the top browser.

Comment: How tall is your nav bar? Also, will you post your code so it's easier to deduce what your specific problem is?

Comment: Hello my nav bar is 40px and the space between my nav bar and the top browser is also 40 px. so the above item shouldn't fix to the browser(bottom) but to the 40px. my source is running on local, so its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change a variable in code from
var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 70;

to 
var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 40;

that should fix your problem with specifying height

Answer (score 0):

Without you posting your code this is the best I can do based on your description.

Change your Javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        var navHeight = 40; //Match the distance of your nav bar from the top of the window
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
            $('nav').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else {
            $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi again. so i finally uploaded it. here is my code http://quranen.dk/index.php/1#start-0 (you have to minimize the browser to tablet/phone size to see the effect. there is a jump from the content to the top(i have no idea why). and btw i changed the nav to .nav4 (just so you know).  can you pleas have a look?

Comment: The reason the content jumps is because when the nav is set to a `position: fixed` then it takes it out of the document flow, so the height of the nav is no longer pushing that content down.  --- Did my answer above solve your original problem?

Comment: hello @Diddle Dot. it doesn't work properly. if you go on the phone and scroll down, the menu is hidden for like 2-3 sec then it shows up. do you know why? or do you have any idea why it does that?